# Can the repetition in this line be avoided?

Tags: python, repeat, non-repetitive

`'=' not in access and name + '.' not in access`

I hope to avoid the multiplicity of `not in access`s in a line of Python code. I've used expression evaluation loops for cases of higher numbers of repetitions for convenience but it just seems odd at two.

Comment: I think you answered your own question is some way: is it really worth it?

Comment: It just seems so unpythonic.

Comment: `re.search('=|' + name + '[.]', access) is None` avoids the repetition, but I don't think mine is any better than yours.

Comment: I don't think using an arguably obscure and just as long expression just for the sake of not repeating 3 words is more pythonic...

Comment: I kind of expected something aesthetically pleasing like `'=', name + '.' not in access`, I guess.

Comment: understood, I guess if there was an obvious non ambiguous syntax for this type of tests it would have been adopted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
all(s not in access for s in ('=', name + '.'))
```

It's up to you to decide if this is simpler than your code - but at least it avoids having to write `not in access` *twice*.